# Iterate through points in QGIS Processing Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-modeler, service-area

I have a goal to build certain Service Areas from the points based on the distance in their attribute table.

I've built a Model which takes the points and the road network. Then I've tried to use 'Service Areas (from layer)'. The problem is that 'Service Areas (from layer)' takes only one particular distance for all points. However I want to iterate through the points and build various Service Areas with different distance from the attribute table.

How can I perform an iteration process in the Graphical Modeler?

Comment: Perhaps you could use the iterative execution of algorithms option available in many tools - the green arrows pointing to each other button.  As for an interator in the graphical modeler this might be interesting: https://github.com/qgis/qgis-enhancement-proposals/issues/108

Comment: @johns Thanks for your answer! I've seen this proposal but I can't see any answer there :/ The green button also doesn't help because it creates several distinct vector layers with 1 feature instead of 1 layer with several features

Comment: It seems that I can't iterate over the points to build service areas with various distance so probably Python script may help. 
I am new to PyQGIS but i believe that it must be easy like "for point in points layer: service_area(point.geometry, point.distance)